# CSS styling a table of contents

Tags: html, css, tableofcontents

I'm trying to replicate the following table of contents:

[image]

I've gotten pretty close with the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/33Kgn/2/

```
.list li {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:330px;
}

.list li:after {
    font-family: Times New Roman;
    font-size: 120%;
    content:".................";
    text-indent: -1px;
    display:block;
    letter-spacing:34px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.list li span {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding-right:5px;
}

.list li .number {
    float:right;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:5px;
}

<div style="margin:25px 22px 200px 22px;">
 <div style="text-align:center;font-size:150%;letter-spacing:.1em;margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:-.1em;">CONTENTS</div>
  <ul class="list" style="padding-left:180px;">
   <li style="margin:0 0 .6em 0;"><span>EDITOR&rsquo;S INTRODUCTION</span><span class="number">ix</span></li>
   <li style="margin:0 0 .5em 0;"><span style="padding-left:.6em;">1. Historical</span><span class="number">ix</span></li>
    <li style="margin:0 0 .5em 0;"><span style="padding-left:.6em;">2. Epistemology</span><span class="number">xii</span></li>
   <li style="margin:0 0 .5em 0;"><span style="padding-left:.6em;">3. Epistemology of Morals</span><span class="number">xx</span></li>
   <li style="margin:0 0 .5em 0;"><span style="padding-left:.6em;">4. Psychology of Morals</span><span class="number">xxvi</span></li>
   <li style="margin:0 0 .5em 0;"><span style="padding-left:.6em;">5. The Moral System</span><span class="number">xxx</span></li>
   <li style="margin:0 0 1.5em 0;"><span style="padding-left:.6em;">6. Morals and Theology</span><span class="number">xliii</span></li>
   <li style="margin:0 0 .5em 0;"><span>A REVIEW OF THE PRINCIPAL QUESTIONS IN MORALS</span><span class="number">1</span></li>
   <li style="margin:0 0 .5em 0;"><span>INDEX</span><span class="number">297</span></li>
  </div>
 </div>
```

But as you can see if you follow the link, the "A REVIEW..." and "INDEX" part doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED TO ADD: The difficulty here lies in the indentation and line-wrapping of "A REVIEW OF THE PRINCIPAL QUESTIONS IN MORALS". So this question does not yet have an answer.

Comment: Maybe you can create a grid and right justify the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/UvazAH/)

Use `display: inline;` instead of `display: inline-block;`

in your `list li span{...}` CSS class

```
list li span {
    display: inline;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost right, but I can't get `text-indent` to work with "A REVIEW..." (I tried `<li style="margin:0 0 .5em 0; text-indent:-.6em; padding-left:.6em;">`). Do you know how to make the indentation work?

Comment: Change the value under .list li from width:330px; to some larger value, like width:500px;